# Microfocus COBOL - Remote debugging requires ALL programs to be compiled for debugging?

Tags: debugging, cobol, microfocus

Being new to Microfocus Cobol, I've setup a debug config to remotely debug programs that reside on an AIX server. The whole system consists of many programs. Only the programs that must be debugged have been compiled to .int, all others are .gnt files.

When debugging, the program starts as expected, but as soon as it calls a program that was compiled to gnt (no debug), the debug session terminates with this message:
`Loaded: /lib/XAH90001.gnt- Not compiled for debugging`. If I debug on the AIX machine itself with the less user friendly animator, it just runs the called program.

Can this be fixed for remote debugging? Is it capable in any way to just run the gnt's I don't want to debug?

Comment: From my experience: ensure that you don't use source breakpoints (sourcefile / line, or click on the debug indicator) but only use program breakpoints.
In any case: I gave up remote debugging with MF, either use remote-workspaces (likely not possible on aix) or use an environment that has good remote-debugging options (like GnuCOBOL and gdbserver).

Comment: In any case: when you use the debugging options of the mf extension, then you have a licensed MF installation - and therefore should have access to the support, too - they were quite helpful (even when it turns out "that's a regression unlikely to change")